# pandas: group by column and add numerated duplicate columns to new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as this

```
Page KeyWord date
1    hello   mon
1    good    mon
2    holy    tues
2    brown   wed
2    crazy   wed
```

need the output dataframe to be

```
Page KeyWord_1 KeyWord_2 KeyWord_3 date_1 date_2 date_3
1    hello     good      NULL      mon    mon    NULL
2    holy      brown     crazy     tues   wed    wed
```

basically the dataframe should add enough columns to satisfy the largest number of duplicate page numbers so in the above case, we see that there were 3 duplicates for Page (there were 3 instances of page 2) so it should add that many numbered duplicate columns besides the groupby column.

just to show another example

**input:**

```
Page KeyWord date
1    hello   mon
1    good    mon
2    holy    tues
2    brown   wed
```

**output:**

```
Page KeyWord_1 KeyWord_2 date_1 date_2 
1    hello     good      mon    mon   
2    holy      brown     tues   wed
```

Answer (score 1):

One way, which goes to a MultiIndex:

```
In [11]: res = df.pivot_table(index="Page", columns=df.groupby("Page").cumcount(), aggfunc="first")

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
     KeyWord                date
           0      1      2     0    1     2
Page
1      hello   good   None   mon  mon  None
2       holy  brown  crazy  tues  wed   wed
```

You can then flatten the columns if you really need:

```
# python 3
In [13]: [f"{title}_{str(i+1)}" for title, i in res.columns]
Out[13]: ['KeyWord_1', 'KeyWord_2', 'KeyWord_3', 'date_1', 'date_2', 'date_3']

# python 2
In [14]: [title + "_" + str(i+1) for title, i in res.columns]
Out[14]: ['KeyWord_1', 'KeyWord_2', 'KeyWord_3', 'date_1', 'date_2', 'date_3']

In [15]: res.columns = [title + "_" + str(i+1) for title, i in res.columns]

In [16]: res
Out[16]:
     KeyWord_1 KeyWord_2 KeyWord_3 date_1 date_2 date_3
Page
1        hello      good      None    mon    mon   None
2         holy     brown     crazy   tues    wed    wed
```

Comment: We can combine the column to one :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
df['new']=df.groupby('Page').cumcount().add(1)
df=df.set_index(['Page','new']).unstack()
df.columns=df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)

Out[870]: 
     KeyWord_1 KeyWord_2 KeyWord_3 date_1 date_2 date_3
Page                                                   
1        hello      good      None    mon    mon   None
2         holy     brown     crazy   tues    wed    wed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_table` function to achieve such. Below code would do the work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
[1, "hello", "mon"],
[1, "good", "mon"],
[2, "holy", "tues"],
[2, "brown", "wed"],
[2, "crazy", "wed"]])
df.columns = ["Page", "KeyWord", "date"]

df_out = pd.pivot_table(df, index="Page", values = ["KeyWord","date"], columns = df.groupby(['Page']).cumcount()+1, aggfunc="first")
df_out.columns = [key + "_" + str(date) for key, date in df_out.columns]
```

So if your original `DataFrame` is:

```
>>> df
   Page KeyWord  date
0     1   hello   mon
1     1    good   mon
2     2    holy  tues
3     2   brown   wed
4     2   crazy   wed
```

Then `df_out` would be:

```
>>> df_out
     KeyWord_1 KeyWord_2 KeyWord_3 date_1 date_2 date_3
Page                                                   
1        hello      good      None    mon    mon   None
2         holy     brown     crazy   tues    wed    wed
```